# Upper bound for $\sum_{i=2}^{n} 1/(i\log(i))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation, asymptotics

I tried to find the asymtotic upper bounds for these summations
$$\sum_{i=2}^{n} 1/(i\log(i)) \text{ and } \sum_{i=2}^{n} 1/(i\log(i)\log\log(i)) .$$

My guess is that they might be bounded by $O(\log\log n)$ and $O(\log\log\log n)$ repectively, but I don't know how to show it. Could you please show me how to bound these?

All I know for now is that they both diverge by checking in Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Start summing from $i=3$ (to have non negative terms) and look up Cauchys Integral test for convergence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\log(\log x)=\frac{1}{x\log x},\qquad \frac{d}{dx}\log(\log(\log(x)))=\frac{1}{x\log(x)\log\log(x)},\tag{1}$$
and both $\log(\log(x))$ and $\log(\log(\log x)))$ are concave increasing functions for $x\geq 3$, so the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality) proves your claim. It also proves that the hidden constant inside the $O(\ldots)$ notation is just $1$.